# Error when obtaining data from an html form to be saved in DB using an endpoint developed with Spring Boot 3

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, spring-boot, forms

You know, I can't fill a database with data from an HTML form with Spring boot 3, This is the form:

```
<div class="section contact" id="contact">
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div class="contact-form-card">
                    <h4 class="contact-title">Send a message</h4>
                    <form action="http://localhost:8080/posts/reg" method="post">
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="nombre" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nombre *" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="apellido" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Apellido *" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email *" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea name="msg" class="form-control" placeholder="Message *" rows="7" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                    
                </div>
```

And this is the end point I've made:

```
@PostMapping("/reg")
    public ResponseEntity<DatosRespuestaCompletaPost> registrarPost(@RequestBody @Valid DatosRegistroPost datosRegistroPost,
                                                                    UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder) {
        System.out.println("Succesful submit");
        System.out.println(datosRegistroPost);
        Post post = postRepository.save(new Post(datosRegistroPost));
        DatosRespuestaCompletaPost datosRespuestaCompletaPost =  new DatosRespuestaCompletaPost(post.getId(), post.getNombre(), post.getApellido(), post.getEmail(), post.getTelefono(), post.getMsg(), post.getActive());
        URI url = uriComponentsBuilder.path("/posts/{id}").buildAndExpand(post.getId()).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(url).body(datosRespuestaCompletaPost);
    }
```

I'd be very grateful if someone would be so kind helping me.

I've tryed to use a JS code to convert what I receive from the form to an application/json format, this is the code I've tryed:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("contact").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            // Captura los valores del formulario
            var formData = {
                nombre: $("#nombre").val(),
                apellido: $("#apellido").val(),
                email: $("#email").val(),
                msg: $("#msg").val()
            };

            // Envía los datos como JSON
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/posts/reg",
                contentType: "application/json",  // Establecer el tipo de contenido a JSON
                data: JSON.stringify(formData),   // Convertir el objeto formData a JSON
                success: function (response) {
                // Manejar la respuesta del servidor cuando la solicitud se completa exitosamente
                console.log("Respuesta del servidor:", response);
                // Puedes realizar otras acciones aquí, como actualizar la interfaz de usuario o    mostrar un mensaje de éxito.
                },
               error: function (error) {
                // Manejar errores en la solicitud
                console.log("Error en la solicitud:", error);
                // Puedes mostrar un mensaje de error al usuario o tomar otras medidas según el tipo    de error.
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```